# Error following upgrade to Mathematica 14.0: Classify: TargetDevice -> GPU requires restart

Tags: machine-learning, gpu

I recently upgraded Mathematica from 13.3 to 14.0 on my workstation. When I attempted to execute a script that ran without any issues on 13.3, I suddenly get an error associated with the Classify function, i.e.

```
Classify: TargetDevice -> GPU requires a restart of your Wolfram Language session
```

An earlier thread suggests that this error was generated due to paclet incompatibilities.

[Version 12.3.1 Problems with NetTrain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250749/version-12-3-1-problems-with-nettrain)

I have confirmed that the Paclet MXNetResources (v. 14.0.28) is part of my Mathematica 14 installation. However, I'm not sure if this is what is causing the error, and furthermore, before I attempt to delete the MXNetResources paclet, I would like to verify that doing so would not disrupt dependencies within Mathematica (for instance, would the Classify function still work?)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [Version 12.3.1 Problems with NetTrain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250749/version-12-3-1-problems-with-nettrain) Namely, it might be due to some incompatibilities in your installed paclets.

Comment: Thank you for the link. What can I do about this - how do I determine which paclets are causing the incompatibility, and should they be removed/replaced? Is this an issue that Wolfram Research would have to deal with?

Comment: Have you tried executing `PacletFind["MXNetResources"]` to see if this particular paclet is installed on your system?

Comment: PS: Even though the error I've encountered is probably similar in nature to the one described in the linked thread, it is not identical because I'm dealing with a more recent Mathematica version 14 vs 13 rather than 13 vs. 12. Consequently, the specific paclet that was causing the error described in the link thread probably doesn't apply to me, and I would appreciate it if my thread could be reopened since the patch suggested for v 13 will not resolve this issue.

Comment: There is PacletObject MXNetRsources Version 14.0.28 installed. I'm hesitant to remove it since I'm not sure this is what is causing the problem, and I'm not familiar enough with what this object is doing to be confident this won't cause other disruptions.

Comment: So my question is this: MXNetResources is installed in version 14. How can I verify that this is what is causing the TargetDevice error, and if I were to uninstall MXNetResources, what dependencies could be effects?